# nth-child or first/last-child selectors don't work. How to apply them right way?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a structure:

```
<div id="div">
    <ul class="ul">
        <li class="li_one">
        </li>
        <li class="li_two">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to set `background:red` to the second `li` element (class "li_two") using pseudo-selectors and want to begin from the most outer div. I'm trying to this way:

```
#div > ul:nth-child(1) { background:red; }   // works but wrong, sets background to ul
#div ul:last-child { background:red; }   // doesn't set to any element
#div ul:first-child { background:red; }  // again sets to ul but not to li
#div [class=li_two] { background:red; }  // only this one works fine
```

Is it possible to set style to `li_two` from `#div` using `:nth-child` or `:last-child` or `:first-child` selectors? How to do it?

Comment: If you want to change the `li` elements, then you have to select them: `#div > ul > li:nth-child(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**#div li:last-child**

Your 2nd option was almost right :) I think you misunderstood what last-child does. xx:last-child It doesn't select the last child element of element xx; it selects every xx element that is the last child of it's parent.

[Some reading](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp).

[I've created a JSFiddle for you to test it](http://jsfiddle.net/TV3Vk/)

Answer (score 2):

`:nth-child()` and the other pseudo-classes should be applied to the child elements, not the parent. Apply those pseudo-classes to the `li`s:

```
#div ul li:last-child {
    background: red;
}
```